# Sharepoint Extension ListView CommandSet - not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I created a site page and then inside that I added a List webpart, and then choose the list I wanted.

Then I put the link of that page in my extension on pageUrl in `serve.json`.

But the extension is not showing. Also if I tried to use the direct URL of the view(not the site page) the extension shows.

Any idea on whats the problem here??